# How do I extract specific data from a CSV file using numpy in python?

Tags: python, numpy, csv

The question is: How many sample points have an odd ID and are also along the watercourse with an odd ID?
and this is my data, the ID is the objectid and the watercourse is the segment, I have been looking for solutions non-stop and trying different things but I cant seem to figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

```
`
['OBJECTID' 'SEGMENT' 'LATDD' 'LONDD']
 ['1' '19574' '39.5575829' '-121.5143903']
 ['2' '19574' '39.5618551' '-121.5148911']
 ['3' '19574' '39.5676358' '-121.5171075']
 ['4' '19574' '39.5771943' '-121.5230478']
 ['5' '19610' '39.520367' '-121.5076167']
 ['6' '19610' '39.5158194' '-121.5065338']
 ['7' '19610' '39.5113691' '-121.50292']
 ['8' '22222' '38.5890322' '-120.8394546']
 ['9' '22222' '38.5918861' '-120.8343423']
 ['10' '22222' '38.596403' '-120.8332479']
 ['11' '25658' '39.3018132' '-121.178298']
 ['12' '25658' '39.3077033' '-121.167993']
 ['13' '25658' '39.3030202' '-121.1552739']
 ['14' '25830' '39.0447288' '-121.1947185']
 ['15' '25830' '39.0502274' '-121.188941']
`



I have tried changing the data type to try and loop over the data through an array, among many other things.
```

Comment: Show the code you've written so far, and what's wrong with it. Where is this data coming from? What kind of output do you need? Why do you think NumPy comes into it? (I wouldn't use NumPy here.)

Comment: Try looking at [How to Read CSV Files with NumPy?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-read-csv-files-with-numpy/?adlt=strict&toWww=1&redig=90D67DBD8A314ABE8C69FEED7A42B9BF)